# Hide code if there is a cookie

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cookies

I have tried all kinds of different codes, php, javascript, but I cannot get it to work the way I want to. Let me explain:

First of all, my code should check for a cookie. If there is a cookie, it should NOT show this code:

```html
<ul>
  <li><a id="demo03" href="#modal-03">DEMO03 7</a>
  </li>
</ul>




<!--DEMO03-->
<div id="modal-03" style="background-image:url(images/access.jpg); background-size:cover;">
  <!--"THIS IS IMPORTANT! to close the modal, the class name has to match the name given on the ID-->
  <div id="btn-close-modal" class="close-modal-03">
    <!--CLOSE MODAL-->
  </div>

  <div class="modal-content">
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <img src="images/logo.png" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <font color="#bfbaa8">Man skal være over 18 år, for at få adgang til denne side.<br />
                <font size="+4">Indtast dit fødselsår</font>
    <br />
    <input maxlength="4" id="age_validation_input" size="33" align="middle" style="background-color: rgba(191, 186, 168, 0.8); border:none; height:90px; width:380px; color:#3d3b33; padding:15px; font-size:70px; font-weight:bold;" value="F.eks. 1963" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'F.eks. 1963';}"
    onfocus="if (this.value == 'F.eks. 1963') {this.value = '';}">
    </font>
    <br />
    <input type="button" id="age_validation_btn" align="middle" style="background-color: rgba(99, 95, 82, 0.8); border:none; height:65px; width:410px; color:#c4bda4; font-size:40px; font-weight:bold;" value="OK" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <font size="-1" color="#69665b">Ved at klikke "OK" giver du tilladelse til, at webstedet benytter cookies.</font>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then I have a javascript snippet. That, if everything is right, should set a cookie (the cookie that will be searched for when entering the site, as mentioned above). This is the code and the //////////// is where the cookie should be created.

```js
$('#age_validation_btn').on('click', function() {

  var age = parseInt($('#age_validation_input').val(), 10);
  var currentYear = (new Date).getFullYear();
  var calculatedYear = currentYear - 123;
  var oldage = age - calculatedYear;

  if (age > currentYear) {
    swal("Hov!", "Vi er ikke nået til det år endnu.", "error");
    return false;
  }

  if (oldage < 5) {
    swal("Hov!", "Du skal indtaste et gyldigt fødselsår.", "error");
    return false;
  }

  if (isNaN(age) || age == 'F.eks. 1963') {
    swal("Hov!", "Du skal indtaste dit fødselsår, for at få adgang til denne side.", "error");
    return false; //stop the validation here
  }

  if (new Date().getFullYear() - age >= 18) {
    //////////////////////////////
    //////////////////////////////
    //////////////////////////////
    $('#btn-close-modal').trigger('click');
  } else {
    location.href = 'noaccess.html';
  }
});
```

Can anyone help me? I have been trying to make it for quite some time now, without luck :-(

For an example, I have tried this... 
This code is the code that should hide the code:

```html
<?php
if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
    // nothing should happen, pass user
} else {
    echo '
  <ul>
    <li><a id="demo03" href="#modal-03">DEMO03 7</a>
    </li>
  </ul>




  <!--DEMO03-->
  <div id="modal-03" style="background-image:url(images/access.jpg); background-size:cover;">
    <!--"THIS IS IMPORTANT! to close the modal, the class name has to match the name given on the ID-->
    <div id="btn-close-modal" class="close-modal-03">
      <!--CLOSE MODAL-->
    </div>

    <div class="modal-content">
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      <img src="images/logo.png" />
      <br />
      <br />
      <font color="#bfbaa8">Man skal være over 18 år, for at få adgang til denne side.<br />
                <font size="+4">Indtast dit fødselsår</font>
      <br />
      <input maxlength="4" id="age_validation_input" size="33" align="middle" style="background-color: rgba(191, 186, 168, 0.8); border:none; height:90px; width:380px; color:#3d3b33; padding:15px; font-size:70px; font-weight:bold;" value="F.eks. 1963">
      </font>
      <br />
      <input type="button" id="age_validation_btn" align="middle" style="background-color: rgba(99, 95, 82, 0.8); border:none; height:65px; width:410px; color:#c4bda4; font-size:40px; font-weight:bold;" value="OK" />
      <br />
      <br />
      <font size="-1" color="#69665b">Ved at klikke "OK" giver du tilladelse til, at webstedet benytter cookies.</font>
    </div>
  </div>
    ';
}
?>
```

And this is the part that should create the cookie:

```
$('#age_validation_btn').on('click', function() {

    var age = parseInt($('#age_validation_input').val(), 10);
    var currentYear = (new Date).getFullYear();
    var calculatedYear = currentYear - 123;
    var oldage = age - calculatedYear;

    if(age > currentYear) {
        swal("Hov!", "Vi er ikke nået til det år endnu.", "error");
        return false;
    }

    if(oldage < 5) {
        swal("Hov!", "Du skal indtaste et gyldigt fødselsår.", "error");
        return false;
    }

    if(isNaN(age) || age == 'F.eks. 1963') {
        swal("Hov!", "Du skal indtaste dit fødselsår, for at få adgang til denne side.", "error");
        return false;//stop the validation here
    }

    if(new Date().getFullYear() - age >= 18) {  
        <? $cookie_name = "user"; ?>
        $('#btn-close-modal').trigger('click'); 
    } else {
        location.href = 'noaccess.html';
    }
});
```

Comment: add at least one of the ways you tried to create the cookie, so we can troubleshoot... also check the dev tools of your browser and check if the cookies is actually created...

Comment: Okay here we go: done

Comment: I see nothing that would be setting cookies anywhere in your code... so can you provide at least one example of the many you tried?

Comment: you still haven't shown how you try to actually set the cookie

Comment: Ups! Sorry, the bottom code is updated! the 5th line from the bottom of the bottom code, sets the cookie

Comment: the 5th line from the bottom is php and is simply a declaration of a variable

Comment: I have changed that in my code, using setCookie.. But the problem with that example is, that the modal never shows up?

Answer (score 3):

1. PHP - show code if cookie is NOT set instead of hiding the code if it IS set:

```
<?php
if(!isset($_COOKIE["user"])) { ?>
  <ul>
    <li><a id="demo03" href="#modal-03">DEMO03 7</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
<?php } ?>
```

2. JS - using https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie :

```
if (new Date().getFullYear() - age >= 18) { 
     Cookies.set("user","ok");
     $('#btn-close-modal').trigger('click');
 } else {
     Cookies.remove("user");
    location.href = 'noaccess.html';
 }
```

This assumes you want to hide the UL the NEXT time they visit

Comment: Unfortunately, the modal doesn't even show up now. It is correct, that the modal should show up, and when entered it should not show up again (for a day or something like that), but it doesn't show the modal at all.

Comment: I put a ! in front of asset and that make the modal show. Now the button won't work? Is that because it sets the cookie before the btn-close-modal is called?

Comment: Press F12 in the browser - did you include the cookie JS file?

Comment: You need to show the code when the cookie is not set - then the ! (not) goes in front of the isset

Comment: What js file? Yes I have added the ! in front of it.

Comment: The cookie script that I suggest you use

Comment: Without expiry it lasts until you close the browser - use `Cookies.set('name', 'value', { expires: 7});` for a week (see documentation)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide the html, when the cookie is not set, than modify your php code from this:

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
    // nothing should happen, pass user
} else {
//your html code here
}
```

to this:

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
//your html code here
}
```

(attention to the exclamation mark before the isset function)

Answer (score 0):

You can use these functions to create and get a cookie (this exemple comes from : http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

```
var getCookie = function(cname) {
var name = cname + "=";
var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1);
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
}
    return "";
}

var setCookie = function(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}
```

To set you cookie use this :

```
setCookie("MyCookie", "MyValue", 365)
```

and in your document ready function you can test it with

```
getCookie("MyCookie")
```

Comment: I have tried all types of different codes and snippets, but I cannot seem to implement it in a way that makes the code do what I want it to - as I mentioned above :/

Comment: To hide your section if the cookie is present, wrap the code to hide with a div with some id you choose, and use $(document).ready(function() { if( !!getCookie("MyCookie")) { $('#mydivtohide').hide() } });